# Azure Vnet Peering vs Vnet Integration

Tags: azure, vnet

I am trying to Azure web app to IAAS VM and both of them are in different VNet's. Can some help me to understand the difference between Azure Vnet Perring & Vnet Integration. and which approach will work best in this context.

Comment: Use Peering to connect 2 Vnets.

Answer (score 1):

Vnet Integration -Gives your app to access to resources in your VNet. And it is used only to make outbound calls from your app into your VNet.but it doesn't grant inbound private access to your app from the VNet.

for more details you may check with these links

1)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#:~:text=VNet%20Integration%20gives%20your%20app%20access%20to%20resources,outbound%20calls%20from%20your%20app%20into%20your%20VNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#:%7E:text=VNet%20Integration%20gives%20your%20app%20access%20to%20resources,outbound%20calls%20from%20your%20app%20into%20your%20VNet).

Vnet Peering -It allows to connecting Virtual networks via azure infrastructure. It offers higher bandwidth connectivity between virtual networks.

for more details you may check with these links

1)[https://techijack.com/azure-vnet-and-vnet-peering/#:~:text=Azure%20VNet%20Peering%20VNet%20Peering%20allows%20connecting%20virtual,It%20offers%20higher%20bandwidth%20connectivity%20between%20virtual%20networks](https://techijack.com/azure-vnet-and-vnet-peering/#:%7E:text=Azure%20VNet%20Peering%20VNet%20Peering%20allows%20connecting%20virtual,It%20offers%20higher%20bandwidth%20connectivity%20between%20virtual%20networks).